# R: SQL into pivoted xts object

Tags: r, merge, pivot, xts

A simple query returns 3 columns: instrument, date, price

Data as follows:

```
library("xts")
dta = data.frame(
  sample(x=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), size=367, replace=TRUE),
  c(as.Date('2016-01-01') + 0:366), 
  c(0:366))
names(dta) <- c("instr", "date", "price")
```

What I want is a pivoted xts-object that looks as follows:

```
            "a"   "b"   "c"   "d"   "e"   "f"
2016-01-01  1     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2016-01-02  NA    2     NA    NA    NA    NA
2016-01-03  3     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2016-01-04  NA    NA    NA    NA    4     NA
...
```

I was thinking about splitting the data into "instrument"-vectors:

```
list_of_instr_vectors <- split(dta, dta$instr)
```

Turn all the data.frames of the list into xts-objects and merge.xts those.

Maybe it would be simpler to turn the data.frame from the start into an xts:

```
xts_dta = as.xts(dta, order.by = dta$date)
```

And pivot that data... but how?

I am sure, there is a simple way to accomplish this common task... but how?

Thanks for any hint!
Marco

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reshape data from long to wide format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  It might be possible to use the methods in the link but since we are dealing with xts series those are not really the best solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `read.zoo` with the `split` argument:

```
z <- read.zoo(dta, split = 1, index = 2)
as.xts(z)
```

Comment: Wow! So simple! The perfect solution! I will have a look into the zoo-package! Thanks!